# Equilibrium in Grand cannonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In Grand Cannonical ensemble, where we have a system and reservoir with only energy and particle exchange possible; after $t=0$, there is energy and particle exchange taking place. After equilibrium is reached, (when $T$ and $\mu$ become equal for system and reservoir)-does energy or particle exchange stop between system and reservoir?
    Also, before equilibrium, were $\mu$ and $T$ equal for the system & reservoir?

Here, $\mu$=chemical potential, and $T$=Temperature

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if you're getting your concepts right !! In statistical mechanics, you don't study how the system evolves to a equilibrium state, you just take a system in equilibrium.

In the Grand Canonical ensemble, the system is still in equilibrium although there is exchange of energy and particles.

Lastly, the chemical potential and temperature are equal for the system and reservoir only when they are in equilibrium not before getting equilibrated. In fact, one way of defining equilibrium would be to say that these parameters are equal for both the system and reservoir.

Comment: But @user35952, i've seen in page 5 of pathria , 1st paragraph that when two systems are brought into thermal contact, exchange takes place till equilibrium is reached. After that, no net energy exchange takes place between the two systems. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Yes, the exchange of particles (or energy) takes place as long as a common chemical potential (or temperature) is attained between the two systems. However, this process reaching the equilibrium state by exchange of particles (or energy) is not explained by statistical mechanics